# User-defined code folding regions in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any built-in functionality or plugin that would allow me to define my own custom regions for code folding? I am using version 4.8.0 (Photon release)

In particular, I am interested in folding certain parts of .java files where I am needing to declare a lot of variables.

Comment: Depends on the content type you want to define regions for.  If you open file "x.y" and ".y" is not already mapped to a content type, then yes you can write a folding structure provider for the generic editor.  You may need to provide additional details on the type of text/content for which you want folding support

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I edited my original post with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add folding regions to Java sources, you can implement the extension "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.foldingStructureProvider".  To do this, you create an eclipse plug-in project (requires Eclipse PDE) and add an extension point to your plugin.xml.  Then you create a class that implements IJavaFoldingStructureProvider and possibly IJavaFoldingStructureProviderExtension.

Folding regions are added like this:

```
FoldingStructureComputationContext context

IRegion normalized = alignRegion(new Region(offset, length), context);
if (normalized != null) {
    Position position = createMemberPosition(normalized, (IMember) element);
    if (position != null) {
        boolean isCollapsed = false, isComment = false;
        context.addProjectionRange(new JavaProjectionAnnotation(isCollapsed, element, isComment), position);
    }
}
```

See DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider for alignRegion, createMemberPosition, etc.  offset and length are determined by your code.